# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined- Header.map

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Not really sure how to define the following props in order to get a render test working.
Line error:

return headersJSON.header.map

If this.extractDataFromXML was this.props.extractDataFromXMl would be easier, just mock into a function and return []. Using shallow to render my component

```
renderHeaders = () => {
let headersJSON = this.extractDataFromXML({ firstKey: 'header', xml: this.props.tableData.headers })

return headersJSON.header.map((headerName, idx) => {
  return (
    <th name={headerName['_']}>{headerName['_']}</th>
  )
 })
```

Here is my how I defined my props in order to render correctly in my test

```
const baseProps = {
 setCurrentColumn,
 tableData:{
    headers:'<header></header>',
    body:[],
 },
 className:[],
}
```

How could I adjust  headers:'' in order to solve the error 
Thanks

Comment: You need to have a mock of `headersJSON` too.

Comment: Colin , did not work   . I did the following const headersJSON = jest.fn (() => {
  return {
    header:[],
    }
});

Comment: @Colin  what is missing

Comment: I mean in your props. The `headersJSON` needs to be e.g. `{}`.

Comment: I did that already and error still the same

Comment: under baseprops, I erased the mock function and did the following :    headersJSON:{ header:[""]
   },